# Google Map Marker Is not in center

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing Google Map API and I show the map in jQuery Dialog Box. The Map is showing fine but the marker position in not in center, SO please guide me.

How can I make the marker position and map in center?

**Code for the map:**

```
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng('@Model.Latitude', '@Model.Longitude'); 

function initialize() { 
    var mapProp = { 
        center: myCenter, 
        zoom: 15, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    }; 

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp); 
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        position: myCenter, 
        draggable: false, 
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, 
    }); 

    marker.setMap(map); 
}
```

**Code opening the dialog box:**

```
$("#googleMap").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false, 
    height: 600, 
    width: 1000, 
    resizeStop: function (event, ui) { 
    google.maps.event.trigger(googleMap, 'resize') 
}, open: function (event, ui) { 
    google.maps.event.trigger(googleMap, 'resize'); }, 
}); 

$("#btnLocation").click(function () { 
    $("#googleMap").dialog("open"); 
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px"></div> 
<img src="map.jpg" alt="Set Location" id="btnLocation" style="cursor: pointer; height: 35px; width: 35px;" />
```

Comment: Hi! Could you show some code?

Comment: Map COde:
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng('@Model.Latitude', '@Model.Longitude');
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: myCenter,
            zoom: 15,           
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenter,
            draggable: false,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,          
        });
        marker.setMap(map);       
    }

Comment: This is the map code. If you want I will send you the jquery dialog code. Even I am unable to post Image otherwise I will show you that and you will get the issue completely.

Comment: This could be useful :). Could you add the code which opens the dialog?

Comment: $("#googleMap").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 1000,           
            resizeStop: function (event, ui) { google.maps.event.trigger(googleMap, 'resize') },
            open: function (event, ui) { google.maps.event.trigger(googleMap, 'resize'); },
        });    
        $("#btnLocation").click(function () {
            $("#googleMap").dialog("open");
        });
<div id="googleMap" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px"></div>

 <img src="map.jpg" alt="Set Location" id="btnLocation" style="cursor: pointer; height: 35px; width: 35px;" />

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

**1) Define `map` and `marker` outside the function `initialize`, we'll call these later to center the map**

```
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng('@Model.Latitude', '@Model.Longitude');

// DEFINE YOUR MAP AND MARKER 
var map = null, marker = null; 

function initialize() { 
    var mapProp = { 
        center: myCenter, 
        zoom: 15, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    }; 

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp); 
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        position: myCenter, 
        draggable: false, 
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, 
    }); 

    marker.setMap(map); 
}
```

**2) Modify the "open" event of the dialog box to force the map center when opening the dialog box:**

```
$("#googleMap").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false, 
    height: 600, 
    width: 1000, 
    resizeStop: function (event, ui) { 
        google.maps.event.trigger(googleMap, 'resize') 
    }, 
    // OPEN EVENT MODIFIED !
    open: function (event, ui) { 
        google.maps.event.trigger(googleMap, 'resize'); 

        // Force the center of the map
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    }, 
});
```

Have a try and let me know if this works ;)

Comment: I had done the same but the Position of marker is still at  the top left corner  which is not visible to users. We have to move the map to the right to view the marker.

Comment: I tries the same but this doesn't work. So can you please check it again and help me to solve the issue.

Comment: @Littm: you have to remove `var` in front of map and marker inside of function `initialize()`.

Comment: @AntoJurković: Thanks Anto. I work as you said and it work great.:)

Comment: @Liitm : Thanks a lot to you as well. :)

Comment: @AntoJurković: Sorry I was offline but I've just seen that the code was corrected ^_^. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the center of the map to the position of the coordinate you have just clicked.

Do this by adding the following code to your click eventhandler.

```
map.setCenter('MARKER'.getPosition());
```

This needs to be added to the eventlistener like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```

for full example take a look at the google maps api example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple

Comment: var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng('@Model.Latitude', '@Model.Longitude');
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: myCenter,
            zoom: 15,           
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenter,
            draggable: false,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,          
        });
        marker.setMap(map);       
    }

Comment: Let me know where I have to Add Changes. I do it but didn't work. I am using jquery diloag to show map.

Comment: I didn't get the center position when the map loads first time. It is in top right corner. Which Is not shown to users.

Comment: I would wait with initiating the google maps until the popup have been loaded. This would fix your problem.

Comment: Can you please tell me that how could I do it?