# Google Maps not centering on marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to get a client's website to display a variable Google Map with an address defined via ACF Maps on WordPress.

The map itself works per se, with it centering not far away from where the marker is.

However, we cannot get the map to center on the marker itself, which defeats the purpose of the map as the company in question is a property management company listing their properties on the website.

This is my functions code:

```
<?php
    function my_theme_add_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-map', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCXO1En_anHPp9eAXyu5ApV50MdHzsDU5c', array(), '3', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-map-init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/google-maps.js', array('google-map', 'jquery'), '0.1', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_add_scripts' );

function my_acf_google_map_api( $api ){

    $api['key'] = 'API_KEY_HERE';

    return $api;

}

add_filter('acf/fields/google_map/api', 'my_acf_google_map_api');
?>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
window.map;
(function ($) {
function render_map($el) {

    // var
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

    // vars
    var args = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng('data-lat','data-lng'),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // create map               
    window.map = new google.maps.Map($el[0], args);

    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];

    // add markers
    $markers.each(function () {

        add_marker($(this), map);

    });

    // center map
    center_map(map);

}

function add_marker($marker, map) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng'));

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        center: latlng,
        map: map
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push(marker);

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if ($marker.html()) {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: $marker.html()
        });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

            infowindow.open(map, marker);

        });
    }

}

function center_map(map) {
    // vars
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    // loop through all markers and create bounds
    $.each(map.markers, function (i, marker) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng());
        bounds.extend(latlng);
    });
    // only 1 marker?
    if (map.markers.length == 1) {
        // set center of map
        map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        map.setZoom(15);
    } else {
        // fit to bounds
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.acf-map').each(function () {
        render_map($(this));
    });

    function center_map(map) {
        // vars
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        // loop through all markers and create bounds
        $.each(map.markers, function (i, marker) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng());
            bounds.extend(latlng);
        });
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<?php
                $location = get_field('properties_location');
                if( !empty($location) ):
            ?>
            <div class="acf-map">
                <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>"></div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

CSS:

```
.acf-map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: #ccc solid 1px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

I'm guessing it can be fixed by a simple jQuery fix but I can't for the life of me figure out what the fix is.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: is it on the top-left corner?

Comment: The marker is hidden out of sight, just past the top left corner yes.

Comment: if it's on the co-ordinate (0,0) from top-left corner. Then it's a very trivial issue. Let me see what I did?

Comment: Sounds like a CSS/HTML problem (the map div doesn't have a size when the map is rendered) , but I don't see any CSS or HTML in your question.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21824406/7427111 Check if this helps, else will work on it.

Comment: @geocodezip HTML/CSS added to the question.

Comment: @Dhaval Jardosh I will have a look at that now

Comment: Your code as posted works for me (puts the marker in the middle of the map).  Of course you haven't provided a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, so I might be putting the pieces together differently than you are.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/LwsLte5n/1/)

Comment: Why do you have two `center_map` functions?

Comment: We have been trying to get this map to work for a couple of months (the project went on hold so it was a couple of months ago I tried it). I don't actually know why I have a second `center_map` function, but removing it does nothing. I followed the [ACF Google Maps Guide](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/) but this is where I've ended up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what my issue was. It was to do with the bounding box that the map was being displayed in.

I am displaying the maps within a tabbed view underneath the property information ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Nti.png)).

As the Google Maps API won't run unless the map is visible, the centering script wasn't running.

However, I moved all of the Google Maps rendering javascript to run within a tab-click function, to ensure the centering of the maps was rendered.

Sure enough, after moving the code, it now centers the marker.

My new javascript/jquery is as follows:

```
$('ul.tabs li.map').one('click', function () {
    function render_map($el) {

        // var
        var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

        // vars
        var args = {
            zoom: 17,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // create map               
        window.map = new google.maps.Map($el[0], args);

        // add a markers reference
        map.markers = [];

        // add markers
        $markers.each(function () {

            add_marker($(this), map);

        });

        // center map
        center_map(map);

    }

    function add_marker($marker, map) {

        // var
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng'));

        // create marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            center: latlng,
            map: map
        });

        // add to array
        map.markers.push(marker);

        // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
        if ($marker.html()) {
            // create info window
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: $marker.html()
            });

            // show info window when marker is clicked
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                infowindow.open(map, marker);

            });
        }

    }

    function center_map(map) {
        // vars
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        // loop through all markers and create bounds
        $.each(map.markers, function (i, marker) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng());
            bounds.extend(latlng);
        });
        // only 1 marker?
        if (map.markers.length == 1) {
            // set center of map
            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
            map.setZoom(17);
        } else {
            // fit to bounds
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.acf-map').each(function () {
            render_map($(this));
        });
    });
});
```

This runs the code only the first time the tab is clicked to prevent it being re-rendered every time the tab gets clicked. The re-rendering was causing the map to break entirely.